# Как можно (и можно ли вообще) написать custom annotation java @MySingleton, которая бы реализовывала паттерн Singleton?

Tags: java, аннотации, singleton, lombok

Как можно (и можно ли вообще) написать custom annotation java `@MySingleton`, которая бы реализовывала паттерн Singleton (желательно thread safe version)?

Цель - написать custom annotation java `@MySingleton`

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})

public @interface MySingleton {
//logic
}
```

, которая бы превращала пустой класс в Singleton:

```
@MySingleton
class Singleton {
}
```

Предполагается (но не обязательно) использовать вот этот вариант паттерна Singleton:

```
class Singleton {
    private static volatile Singleton instance = null;

    private Singleton(){
    }
    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        //Double checked locking for correct operation in multithreaded applications
        if (instance == null) {
            synchronized (Singleton.class) {
                if (instance == null) {
                    instance = new Singleton();
                }
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Для того, чтобы сделать это аннотация должна создавать в классе:

1. Переменную `private static volatile Singleton instance = null;`
2. private constructor:

   ```
   private Singleton(){
   }
   ```
3. геттер

   ```
   public static Singleton getInstance() {
       //Double checked locking for correct operation in multithreaded applications
       if (instance == null) {
           synchronized (Singleton.class) {
               if (instance == null) {
                   instance = new Singleton();
               }
           }
       }
       return instance;
   }
   ```

Например в Lombok в аннотации `@Getter` уже есть механизм создания геттера в классе (https://projectlombok.org/api/lombok/Getter.html).
Также в Lombok в аннотациях `@NoArgsConstructor` и `@AllArgsConstructor` уже есть механизм создания конструкторов в классе (https://projectlombok.org/api/lombok/package-summary.html).
Возможно, те же способы создания геттеров и конструкторов можно реализовать в аннотации `@MySingleton`.

Если все же невозможно поместить всю логику создания Singleton в одну аннотацию `@MySingleton`, то, может быть, можно разделить логику создания геттеров и конструкторов в аннотациях `@MySingletonGetter` и `@MySingletonConstructor`?

Comment: Используя не самую свежую версию lombok это можно сделать (с некоторыми ограничениями). Вот тут делается именно singleton https://www.baeldung.com/lombok-custom-annotation

Comment: А в новом это вероятно можно сделать используя https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/ExtensionMethod

Answer (score 2):

Я могу ошибаться, но, насколько я понимаю, сами по себе аннотации ничего не делают. Это просто некий вариант интерфейса (о чём говорит их объявление @interface). Подобно тому, как для интерфейса необходимо предоставить класс-реализацию, для аннотации необходим перехватчик. Его можно реализовать с помощью АОП (используя Spring AOP или AspectJ). Тогда для каждого вызова объекта аннотированного класса будет возвращаться не сам объект, а его прокси с накрученной логикой, сгенерированный неявно (точнее в данном случае будет возвращаться синглтон). Либо можно реализовать свой кастомный Spring scope для потокобезопасного синглтона. При настройке бинов Spring также использует проксирование. Наверняка есть ещё какие-то способы.

Comment: Этот ответ нельзя назвать неправильным, но он очень слабо относится к вопросу. Автор хочет делать вещи подобные тем, что делает lombok (т.е. если грубо то автоматическая и прозрачная генерация кода), а это совсем не имеет отношения к тому, что вы тут написали.

Answer (score 1):

Да, возможно.

Но надо понимать, что аннотация - это метаинформация, то есть это не "кусок кода",  а скорее сообщение для остального кода, что на этом коде стоит метка (в вашем случае метка - `@MySingleton`)

Поэтому помимо самой аннотации нужен класс обработчик, который и будет выполнять бизнес-логику по обработке класса, над которым стоит эта аннотация (метка).

> Для того, чтобы сделать это аннотация должна создавать в классе:

Вот это не верно, аннотация ничего создавать не будет, этим занимается класс обработчик.

Учитывая специфику задачи (синглтон), думаю в самом классе (над которым ставим аннотацию) нужно сделать конструктор приватным, но на этом всё - остальной код в классе обработчике.

Класс обработчик будет использовать рефлексию, чтобы получить доступ к приватному конструктору и создать инстанц.

В принципе, по этой логике (аннотация - обработчики) строятся все современные фреймворки на джаве (JUnit, Spring, Hibernate...)

Comment: Как в таком случае должен выглядеть код на Java?

Comment: Вопрос был можно ли и как. Я общий вектор подсказал, а конкретная реализация уже за вами.